# Add only specific repository for Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a very specific case. I have given /home/prashant/git as a base directory for Gerrit.

The git folder has 5 projects: a1.git, a2.git, a3.git, a4.git and a5.git. However, I want only a4.git repository to be used for gerrit review. Rest all should work normally. I want to "enforce" a review only on a4.git.

When the entire folder path is given to gerrit, it will enforce a review on all of the repositories inside that folder. I do not want this. `git push origin ref/....` should send the changes for review only for a4.git and should merge for rest everything.

Does anyone know of any way to do it?

My gerrit and a*.git files happen to be on different machines. Repos are referred by https://gitlab.example.com/admin/a4.git (HTTP)

Answer (score 2):

By default Gerrit requires changes to be reviewed before they reach the target branch, but that's just the default configuration. If you want people to be able to push changes straight to refs/heads/name-of-branch, grant them the [Push permission](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push) for the ref(s) in question.

1. Navigate to the project's settings (e.g. via Projects -> List).
2. Choose the Access tab.
3. Click Edit.
4. For the refs/heads/* reference, click Add Permission and choose Push.
5. Fill in the group the permission should apply to (e.g. Registrered Users) and save the changes.